Do I trust "cost" or "actual time" more when using Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE?
I'm trying to improve the performance of one of our most expensive queries. I'm running EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the sandbox postgres 15 database, which has a much smaller dataset than the production postgres 15 database, and also likely doesn't have the same data patterns that we have in production as well.
SELECT COUNT(ut.id) 
FROM user_task ut
LEFT JOIN person person ON person.id = ut.person_id
LEFT JOIN health_center_group health_center_group ON health_center_group.id = ut.health_center_group_id 
WHERE ut.test_group = ('')
AND ut.status IN (('active')::user_task_status)
AND ut.type IN (('review_consent_form')::user_task_type)
AND ut.assignee_id IS NULL
AND (
  person IS NULL 
  OR person.health_center_permission_pending NOT IN (('exception'), ('multiple_pending'))
)
AND (
  NOT (
    ut.type = 'review_consent_form' 
    AND ut.status IN ('active', 'exception')
    AND health_center_group.persons_imported_at_tg IS NULL
  )
)

 Aggregate  (cost=2591.66..2591.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=4.003..4.005 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=83.67..2589.84 rows=727 width=8) (actual time=0.730..3.980 rows=251 loops=1)
         Filter: ((person.* IS NULL) OR ((person.health_center_permission_pending)::text <> ALL ('{exception,multiple_pending}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=83.39..480.50 rows=728 width=16) (actual time=0.582..3.710 rows=255 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (ut.health_center_group_id = health_center_group.id)
               Filter: ((ut.type <> 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type) OR (ut.status <> ALL ('{active,exception}'::user_task_status[])) OR (health_center_group.persons_imported_at_tg IS NOT NULL))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 24
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_task ut  (cost=55.68..450.84 rows=738 width=32) (actual time=0.324..3.353 rows=279 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (type = 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type)
                     Filter: ((assignee_id IS NULL) AND ((test_group)::text = ''::text) AND (status = 'active'::user_task_status))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4416
                     Heap Blocks: exact=306
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_task_type_idx  (cost=0.00..55.50 rows=4695 width=0) (actual time=0.211..0.211 rows=4735 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (type = 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type)
               ->  Hash  (cost=23.98..23.98 rows=298 width=16) (actual time=0.238..0.238 rows=298 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on health_center_group  (cost=0.00..23.98 rows=298 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.152 rows=298 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using person_pkey on person  (cost=0.29..2.88 rows=1 width=1000) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=255)
               Index Cond: (id = ut.person_id)
 Planning Time: 1.524 ms
 Execution Time: 4.105 ms
(22 rows)

I've found that changing the 11th line of the query from person IS NULL to ut.person_id IS NULL significantly decreases the cost, however it also significantly increases the "actual time" and "execution time":
Aggregate  (cost=1551.69..1551.70 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=15.309..15.311 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1150.85..1549.88 rows=727 width=8) (actual time=13.147..15.291 rows=251 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (ut.person_id = person.id)
         Filter: ((ut.person_id IS NULL) OR ((person.health_center_permission_pending)::text <> ALL ('{exception,multiple_pending}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=83.39..480.50 rows=728 width=16) (actual time=0.932..3.174 rows=255 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (ut.health_center_group_id = health_center_group.id)
               Filter: ((ut.type <> 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type) OR (ut.status <> ALL ('{active,exception}'::user_task_status[])) OR (health_center_group.persons_imported_at_tg IS NOT NULL))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 24
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_task ut  (cost=55.68..450.84 rows=738 width=32) (actual time=0.468..2.637 rows=279 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: (type = 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type)
                     Filter: ((assignee_id IS NULL) AND ((test_group)::text = ''::text) AND (status = 'active'::user_task_status))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4416
                     Heap Blocks: exact=306
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_task_type_idx  (cost=0.00..55.50 rows=4695 width=0) (actual time=0.267..0.267 rows=4735 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (type = 'review_consent_form'::user_task_type)
               ->  Hash  (cost=23.98..23.98 rows=298 width=16) (actual time=0.445..0.446 rows=298 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on health_center_group  (cost=0.00..23.98 rows=298 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.381 rows=298 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=711.65..711.65 rows=28465 width=13) (actual time=11.988..11.989 rows=28465 loops=1)
               Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1508kB
               ->  Seq Scan on person  (cost=0.00..711.65 rows=28465 width=13) (actual time=0.014..7.222 rows=28465 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 13.285 ms
 Execution Time: 15.512 ms
(24 rows)

Cost significantly decreases from 2591.66..2591.67 to 1551.69..1551.70 . However, the “actual time” increases from 4.003..4.005 to 15.309..15.311 and the "execution time" increases from 4.105 ms to 15.512 ms.
I know "cost" is just an estimate (and yes I did run analyze on the tables before doing the analysis), however I don't know how to weigh these metrics against each other when doing analysis on the sandbox DB. Will this change result in a performance improvement or degradation?

"...I've found that changing the 11th line of the query from person to ut.person_id. Well... you are comparing two different queries now. Also, you should always prepend the table alias to all column when you have a query that uses multiple tables.

Since you suspect the production database is significantly different from the one in development, I would retrieve the plan from the production one. Plenty of tools do that.

Finally, if you are concerned about performance, avoid the use of IN. That's a performance killer.

cost depend on your configuration. Let's say you double the costs for both sequential IO and random IO, the cost will double. If your query plan won't change, the time it takes to execute the plan won't change either.

Rows Removed by Filter: 4416 is your problem, you don't have an index on the combination of columns you're filtering

The actual execution time and the actual rows are reality, so that's the reliable information about what really happened.
The first parenthesis that contains the cost and the row estimate are what the database thought was the case. If that diverges from reality, it means that the database's estimates were off, which can be the cause for a bad plan choice.
However, it is difficult to reach a reliable conclusion in your case. The row counts were so low and the execution times so short that the differences might just as well be due to random variations.  Repeat the experiment a few times and see how the execution times vary.  To get more significant results, you need more data.
